# FCM: Image failed to download to display on Push notification for Android Phones

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have integrated @react-native-firebase/messaging in React Native app. Push notification is working perfectly **but sometimes the image couldn't display on push notification** which is sent in the notification payload as like below:

```
{
    "to": "FCM-TOKEN",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Body Text",
        "title": "Title Text",
        "image": "IMAGE-URL"
    },
    "data": {
        ...
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

All works perfectly **but I have found that this issue only in some devices like Samsung, Xiaomi, and which have Android 11 OS. This happens only on Android phones only. For iPhone, it works fine.**

**And, I am getting the below logs from Firebase:**

```
2021-06-28 12:23:21.504 24846-24916/? I/FirebaseMessaging: Starting download of: <IMAGE-URL>
2021-06-28 12:23:26.553 24846-24914/? W/FirebaseMessaging: Failed to download image in time, showing notification without it
```

It's a very strange issue, I couldn't able to find any perfect solution for the last few days, and even Google, Android, and React-Native-Firebase **haven't mentioned this in any release notes of Firebase.**

Let me know if anyone having this kind of problem or any suggestions for this. Thanks in advance.

**Android Dependencies:**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:17.0.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
```

**React-Native Dependencies:**

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5"
"@react-native-firebase/admob": "^10.8.1",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^10.8.1",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.8.1",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^10.8.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.8.1"
```

Comment: Where do you host the image and how large is it. Looks like it's just to big and connection to slow.

Comment: @TarikHuber, We have hosted images on AWS S3 and also use IMGIX. Previously we were using large image files but now we have reduced that image size up to 20-30 kb and also using a 2:1 ratio for image resolution. but still getting this kind of error. 

And I have checked internet connection also very enough speed up to 10Mbps.

Comment: @immodi Hello, sir, no solution found?

Comment: @immodi did you found solution?

Comment: same issue, it says Failed to download image: java.io.FileNotFoundException